# Android - What does that mean when an app sends system intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

I have found a code

```
intent.setAction("android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED");
```

So, this is a system intent means that the app was granted to device administrator, but why it sends those intents?

And this is not a system app

Comment: I think system apps means if you want to change any feature in device then we can access through system intents, like for open camera we use one intent, gmail anything we will use intents so these are system intents.

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: @DavidWasser, in an android virus

Answer (score 0):

Here are examples of the types of applications that might use the Device Administration API:

- Email clients.
- Security applications that do remote wipe.
- Device management services and applications.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html)

More info about [Intent setAction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setAction(java.lang.String)) and [ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver.html#ACTION_DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED)